# VBA excel userform and textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

---

EDIT

I think I might have alongated too much tryin to explain, and I will post a shorter version, cuz I figure it out it might get easier to understand if I don't have to explain the whole process itself. Basically, we have the follow image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcQl7.jpg)

Whenever I type in a cell reference in **(1)** it will type the content of the option button that I selected **(2)** in my worksheets, when I click in the button **CommandButton1**. This content of **(2)** is already stored in a cell. In this case, it will type in the cell B12 "just a value 1". But if I change **(1)** to C9, for example, it will type in the cell C9 "just a value 1", cause that's the option that it's selected.

The whole process has to be done in a way that I don't have to open the vba code to change the cell reference, cause I will have to alter it as many times I can, so... it's easier if I just type in a cell reference in the textbox **(1)**.

Comment: `how to make that textbox (2) recognize that B12 is a cell` - by storing the text "B12" in another cell, with a fixed pre-known address, or in a module-level variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT to follow OP's edit

assuming:

- user form

  is called after "UF"

  upper option button is called after "OptionButton1"

  bottom option button is called after "OptionButton2"

  text box is called after "TextBox1"

  command button is called after "CommandButton1"
- worksheet button

  is a form control

  is called after "Button 1"

  is assigned a "Button1_Click()" macro in some module

then you can use the following code:

**UserForm** code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me
        .Hide
    End With
End Sub
```

**Module code** (where you have the button related code)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    With New UF
        .Show
        
        Select Case True
            Case .OptionButton1
                Range(.TextBox1.Value).Value = .OptionButton1.Caption
            Case .OptionButton2
                Range(.TextBox1.Value).Value = .OptionButton2.Caption
        End Select
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

---

Here I keep the solution for the original OP with two user forms, the second one having to use values grabbed by the first one

use worksheet cells to store values from the "first" user form (option buttons caption and target cell address) to be read by the "second" one

for instance, assuming:

- "first" user form

  is called after "UF1"

  upper textbox is called after "TextBox1"

  median textbox is called after "TextBox2"

  bottom textbox is called after "TextBox3"

  command button is called after "CommandButton1"
- "second" user form

  is called after "UF2"

  upper option button is called after "OptionButton1"

  bottom option button is called after "OptionButton2"

  command button is called after "CommandButton1"
- worksheet helper cells

  "A1" to store the value from UF1 TextBox1
  "A2" to store the value from UF1 TextBox2
  "A3" to store the value from UF1 TextBox3
- worksheet buttons

  are of form controls type

  the one calling UF1 is called after "Button 1" and is assigned a "Button1_Click()" macro in some module

  the one calling UF3 is called after "Button 2" and is assigned a "Button2_Click()" macro in some module

then you can use the following code:

**UserForm 1** code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me
        .Hide
    End With
End Sub
```

**Userform 2** code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me
        .Hide
    End With
End Sub
```

**Module code** (where you put the buttons related code)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    With New UF1
        .Show
        
        Range("A1").Value = .TextBox1.Value
        Range("A2").Value = .TextBox2.Value
        Range("A3").Value = .TextBox3.Value
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()

    With New UF2
        .OptionButton1.Caption = Range("A1").Value
        .OptionButton2.Caption = Range("A2").Value
        
        .Show
    
        Select Case True
            Case .OptionButton1
                Range(Range("A3").Value).Value = .OptionButton1.Caption
            Case .OptionButton2
                Range(Range("A3").Value).Value = .OptionButton2.Caption
        End Select
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply my question. That's not exactly what I am searching for, since every time I will have to change the VBA code if I want to change the cell that I want the value to type in. I will post a shorter version of my question, cuz I think my explanation might have get too long and difficult to understand

Comment: you don't have to change no VBA code at all

Comment: just try it once an you'll see that

Comment: @Sullivan2021 I edited my answer to follow your question edit, which is just a simplified version of my previous answer (I kept for the records) to your original question,